# Finding the order of zeros for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I kinda know the answer, but what I am looking for is a proof.

Let $ f(z) $ be analytic on $ D $ with a zero of order $ m $ at $ z = a $
Let $ g(z) $ be analytic on $ D $ with a zero of order $ n $ at $ z = a $
Let $ m >= n $

Find the order of $ f(z)+g(z) $ at $ z = a $

I am pretty sure that the order is $ m $ because $ m >= n $ but I don't know how to prove it.

Find the order of $ f(z).g(z) $ at $ z = a $

This one I am sure that the order is $ m+n $ but I don't know how to prove it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is $\;n\;$ , in fact. Write

$$f(z)=(z-a)^mh(z)\;,\;\;g(z)=(z-a)^nk(z)\;,\;\;h(a),\;k(a)\neq0\;,\;\;m\ge n\implies$$

$$f(z)+g(z)=(z-a)^n\left[(z-a)^{m-n}h(z)+k(z)\right]\;,\;\;(a-a)^{m-n}h(a)+k(a)=k(a)\neq0$$

so the order of the zero $\;a\;$ in $\;f(z)+g(z)\;$ is $\;n\;$ .

For the product you're right, and you can prove it in a similar way as above.

Comment: What about $ \frac {f(z)}{g(z)} $ It is possible the same way if $m>n$, but what if $m=n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z=a$, you can write $f(z)=(z-a)^mf_1(z)$ where $f_1(a)\neq 0$. Similarly, you can write $g(z)=(z-a)^ng_1(z)$ where $g_1(a)\neq 0$. We are assuming that $n\leq m$.

Then $$f(z)+g(z)=(z-a)^mf_1(z)+(z-a)^ng_1(z)=(z-a)^n[(z-a)^{m-n}f_1(z)+g_1(z)].$$ Let $h(z)=(z-a)^{m-n}f_1(z)+g_1(z)$. If $h(a)=0$, then that would imply $g_1(a)=0$, which would contradict $g_1(a)\neq 0$. Therefore, we can write $f(z)+g(z)=(z-a)^nh(z)$ with $h(a)\neq 0$, so $f+g$ has a zero at $z=a$ of order $n$.

Try doing something similar for $f(z)g(z)$. You intuition is correct: it has a zero of order $mn$.

Comment: I dont see why is this different from other answer?

Comment: The other person posted as I was writing my answer, so I didn't even see it. I thought I would leave it up in case anyone wanted extra explanation.

Comment: What about $\frac {f(z)}{g(z)}$ It is possible the same way if $ m>n $, but what if $ m=n $ ?

Comment: If $m=n$, then $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$. See Snider and Saff, Fundamentals of Complex Analysis, pg 281, Example 2 (all of section 5.6 would be probably be beneficial to read, you can find the text online).